# Ошибка получения данный twittwr api

Tags: twitter, php, авторизация

Твиттер сменил api и у меня слетела авторизация через него, пытаюсь получить инфу так

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=login

Но выдает "Bad Authentication data", думал может надо отправить oauth_token который возвращает приложение после того как авторизует юзера, но нет. Без понятия что делать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно **[Документации Twitter API 1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show)**, **для этого действия требуется авторизация**.
Как можно понять, что именно вы неправильно делаете:
Если у вас уже есть созданное приложение, то выберите его из [списка](https://dev.twitter.com/apps), после чего
перейдите на вкладку OAuth tool
В поле **Request URI** введите **`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json`**
В поле **Request query** введите **`screen_name=login`**
и нажмите кнопку **See OAuth signature for this request**
Вы получите полностью валидный сгенерированный запрос для получения нужной вам информации.

---

Пример кода использования класса **[codebird-php](https://github.com/mynetx/codebird-php)**

```
require_once ('codebird.php');
//Смотреть на вкладке Details вашего приложения: Consumer key и Consumer secret
\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey('YOURKEY', 'YOURSECRET');
$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
//Имя пользователя
$username = 'login';

//Смотреть на вкладке Details вашего приложения: Access token и Access token secret
$cb->setToken('YOURTOKEN', 'YOURTOKENSECRET');
$reply = $cb->users_show("screen_name=$username");
var_dump($reply);
```

Comment: Иии.. Почему-то все равно не работает. Отправляю в заголовках данные, вроде все правильно, но нет. У кого-нибудь есть работающий код без использования сторонних классов? Я выдеру от туда

Comment: И-и-и вот работающий класс. Только что сам проверил: https://github.com/mynetx/codebird-php  
Пример кода добавил в ответ.